# I Want to integrate sms module on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, custom

I have purchased my desired sms API and i have also written the code for that just need to invoke my code on checkout button how can you help me.
Looking for a quick and easy solution
Thanks

Comment: When do you want to trigger the sms?

Comment: when user click on checkout button to place order

Comment: Create a ajax function on click of the function & in controller function you can write your action to do.

Comment: i am new in magento so can you please guide in which file i have to add..

Comment: easy solution is to purchase the readymade extension https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

In app/code/My/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="My\Module\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

In app/code/My/Module/Observer/MyObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //Write your sms code here           $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); //Get order from event observer
        $order_id = $order->getID(); //Get order ID from order
        $order_number = $order->getIncrementId(); //Get order increment ID from order
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId(); //Get customer ID from order
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
        $name = $customer->getName(); //customer name
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get information like order id customer phone number etc...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it safer to do what you have to do after success ordering or even after receiving payment?

I mean in success.phtml or with an observer when order status changes to i.e. Invoiced.

Comment: i want  to sms on successful order placement

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this extension http://ext.topmage.com/Hacky_Smsnotifications.html to trigger SMS while place order, invoice, shipment etc. Its free and opensource and easy to customize (add new events for SMS).

You will only needed API details from SMS subscribing company.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a module for telenor sms api.
It will send an sms to the customer when place an order.
you can Download the module [Here](https://github.com/hafizjee/telenorsmsapi)